# Comando para deixar rodando Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5

Tenho uma instalação do laravel 5.1
Para iniciar, eu estou usando:

> php artisan serve --host=meudominio.com.br --port=8001

Já tentei incluir o & (E comercial) no final, com espaço, mas após executar esse comando, permanece em execução no terminal ubuntu, o que nao é viável. (IMAGEM demonstrativa)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso deixar o meu projeto laravel rodando sem a necessidade de acompanhar no terminal com o `artisan serve` , Li sobre isso, que da pra executar o comando php mas no background , sem a tela das requisições ficar aparecendo, salvando em algum tipo de log.

Alguem pode me ajudar com o comando?

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com a documentação do Laravel:

> Typically, you may use a web server such as Apache or Nginx to serve
>   your Laravel applications. If you are on PHP 5.4+ and would like to
>   use PHP's built-in development server, you may use the serve Artisan
>   command... [Aqui](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/quick)

Esse recurso é destinado à versão de desenvolvimento. A versão do sistema que realmente está em uso, é preferível que esteja rodando em um servidor WEB, tipo apache, nginx entre outros. O texto não é tão claro quanto a essa restrição, apenas da a opção para um servidor de desenvolvimento rodando direto no PHP. Porem, é muito mais provável que um servidor web tenha uma performance muito maior com as requisições do usuário(Pois há anos de otimizações) do que o script que é fornecido junto com o framework.

Caso ainda assim queira rodar a aplicação sem um "terminal oculto". Você pode tentar essas configurações(Não recomendo):

```
ignore_user_abort(1); 
set_time_limit(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Para você conseguir roda um comando em background no linux existe várias formas para fazer isso, entre elas estar o comando "nohup" disponibilizado nos sistemas UNIX, ele permite executar programa de uma forma "desconectada" da sessão atual. Ou seja, se o usuário fizer logout, o comando continuará a rodar em segundo plano, emitindo sua saída para o arquivo "nohup.out" que será criado no diretório corrente (onde o comando foi executado), mas você pode também executar os programas em modo silencioso (Não criará o arquivo nohup.out no diretório).

```
nohup php artisan serve >/dev/null 2>&1 & # Não criará o arquivo nohup.out no diretório

nohup php artisan serve & # Criará o arquivo nohup.out no diretório
```